# Mongodb - Full text search on embedded document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

We have a Person collection with documents looking something like this:

```
{
...
    address: {
        city: 'Miami',
        state: 'Florida',
        street: 'My favorite street'
    }
...
}
```

Now, I want to perform a full text search on the address. I have created a text index on all of the documents fields:

```
db.Person.createIndex({'$**': 'text'}, {name: 'FullTextIndex'})
```

Something is wrong, because it never works for terms in the address field, which is the one that matters in my case.

When I execute the following command:

```
db.Person.find({$text: {$search: 'Florida my favorite street'}})
```

It returns an empty array. What could be happening?

Comment: I followed all the above steps and it's working fine for me (it returns the inserted document). What version of MongoDB are you using?
Maybe it is due to the MongoDB shell client version

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4

Comment: same as me... that odd...

Comment: And what about the server version? are you using a replica set or just a standalone instance?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make new index work just delete your old indexes

```
 db.collection.dropIndex(index)
```

or

```
Model.collection.dropAllIndexes();
```